# Regex Between HTML Tags - VBA

Tags: html, regex, vba

I have a page full of html data that I am scraping from.

There is one occurrence of a "gross amount" field that I am trying to extract.

```
<h3 id="cart_trans_detail_ach_grossamount_lbl">Gross Amount</h3>
<p id="cart_trans_detail_ach_grossamount_txt">$76.99 USD</p>
```

All I want to get from this is `$76.99 USD`

I have tried using Regex Buddy and putting together but regex is not my strong suite. Even something simple like this: `<p id="cart_trans_detail_ach_grossamount_txt">(.*)</p>` matches the whole string and not just what is between the tags.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using JavaScript for this, or a server-side language?

Comment: get the string you want from group index 1.

Comment: What script are you using for the regex???

Comment: This is for VBA so I cant simply use something like jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, using a regex to parse HTML is unrecommended, you should use a HTML/XML parsing library instead. But if you really feel the need to use a regular expression for that, what you are missing is the ungreedy char (?) after your (*) so that your regex stops at the first `</p>` it finds.

```
<p id="cart_trans_detail_ach_grossamount_txt">(.*?)</p>
```

Comment: "unrecommended" is putting it gently.

Comment: No obligatory link? Let me fix that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

(?<=grossamount_txt">\$)(\d*\.?\d*) USD

It works in python and php, it shall also work in Java.
The group(1) gives you back only the amount without other things.

The first parenthesis encloses a positive lookbehind which looks if before the USD amount there is a string related to "grossamount_txt">$".
then the second parenthesis try to match for a numeric amount possibily expressed in integer number and decimal numbers.
Finally there the last part of the pattern is " USD".

You can test it here
https://www.regex101.com/#python 
where you can also find some more detailed explanation.

Here about how lookaround works
http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Hope it helps.